# System Analysis and design of A social Network

Tags: system-analysis

Is It possible to perform a system analysis and design for a Website ( particularly a social Network ) ?

What are the Expected contents will be , In the document ?

can u provide an example , please ?

{ I made a social network (www.sy-stu.com) as to be my graduation project and I want to add a full analysis study to the graduation document , I do have experience in UML and Usecases just the Idea of an analysis of a website is not clear and never perform one before }

thanx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds very ambitious, but I'm sure it's possible.  Unfortunately, I've forgotten a bit of System Analysis, but do adhere to many of its guiding principles for my own projects.  In fact, I would say that most data-driven Web sites are excellent candidates for Systems Analysis and should be used always during Web planning for any project you plan on putting into production.

Straight from the wiki:

1. The development of a feasibility
   study, involving determining whether
   a project is economically, socially,
   technologically and organizationally
   feasible.
2. Conducting fact-finding
   measures, designed to ascertain the
   requirements of the system's
   end-users. These typically span
   interviews, questionnaires, or
   visual observations of work on the
   existing system.
3. Gauging how the
   end-users would operate the system
   (in terms of general experience in
   using computer hardware or
   software), what the system would be
   used for etc.

For the first point, I would analyze different technologies such as ASP.NET, Ruby on Rails and PHP.  Each technology has its strengths and weaknesses.  One key thing to keep in mind is if you plan on making your social network free, you may consider open source technologies over proprietary - as many servers and application frameworks for proprietary projects are costly.  I would also consider Web startup and hosting fees.  If you plan on getting a reseller account with Host Gator, then you would need to factor in monthly billing costs.  If you plan to host your own servers, you may be amazed at the cost of doing so.  For a truly stable system, you would need to put a lot of work and cash into managing your own Web servers.

For the second point, you could probably locate plenty of information on user requirements from similar sites - just check out forums for DIY social networks and see what people are having issues with in the Technical Support section.  Obviously, looking into technology based articles and magazines would be a good place to search on end user expectations - or even just joining Facebook and Twitter - see what they are doing since people seem content.

For the third point, again you can consult your competition and see how the user interface works out.  Is it easy to use?  Is it difficult in some aspects?  If you had to use their system for 8 hours a day at least 5 days a week, what would drive you mad and how would you do it better?  And keep in mind logical work flow as well.  Knowing your user base is important too.  In some systems, you may be developing for other programmers.  Using strong jargon may be fine, but for a social network you must remember that they aren't familiar with Web site data flow and terminology.  So your controls should still make sense to a computer novice and still work securely (don't forget system security too!) and in an organized fashion.

Finally, remember that things happen.  I recently created a back-end site for a client of mine.  I though the system worked very well - and they were very pleased, but I just got an email today that they want the way order items are stored to work differently.  This is why there's a maintenance aspect to the System Development Life Cycle - things change after you finish deploying.  It could also be said that if I had communicated with my client's needs more closely, this could have been resolved.  Fortunately, the change is relatively minor, and we do live in a real world where things don't always work as we expect.  We just do our best :)

As I said earlier, Systems Analysis is a lot of work and should be.  The point of it is to determine that what you are trying to accomplish is feasible and practical without committing to a long term project that could span years.  And always remember that no plan is perfect.  If there were perfect plans, we wouldn't need new systems :).